# fabricjs system is ready - event

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Hi fabricjs contributors,

according to the 'wiki' there is no state events currently - https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events . so there is no way to bind a trigger on 'system ready' state.

of course i can use jQuery(document).ready(function(){...}), but i would also like to know if fabricjs developers had consider to add such event or can propose a way to handle it natively .

thanks for your great work with fabric !

Comment: What do you mean by "ready" event? jQuery's ready represents document availability. In fabric, there's really no availability to listen to. Fabric canvas is instantiated synchronously (so it's ready right away), and all async methods have corresponding callbacks (usually as 2nd argument).